# Trouble evaluating all values of an array in a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write my own function to evaluate input fields to see if they have a value. So I've written this for loop:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    for (var ii = 0; ii < personalInfo.length; ii++) {
      if ($(personalInfo[ii]).val() == 0) {
        $(personalInfoLabels[ii]).addClass("required");
      }
      else{
        $("button").parent("fieldset").slideUp();
      }
    };
});
```

As of now the loop has no problem identifying the positions of the array that are empty and labeling them correctly.

However, if any of the positions have a value the event happens. How can I say if each position of the loop has a value, fire event, but if not label the required field?

A JSFiddle of the code is available at http://jsfiddle.net/bjKX7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-arranged your code a bit, check here:

```
$("#cont-one").click(function () {
    var error = 0;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < personalInfo.length; ii++) {
        if ($(personalInfo[ii]).val() == 0) {
            $(personalInfoLabels[ii]).addClass("required");
            error++;
        } else {
            $(personalInfoLabels[ii]).removeClass("required");
        }
    };
    if (error) {
        return false;
    }
    $("#cont-one").parent("fieldset").slideUp();
});
```

This code will go thru all inputs and add class to those you wanted. It will also remove that class in case they are filled. I added also a `return false;` in case there are errors so the function & form submission will stop here (in case of error).

Keep in min that input fields are self closed, so add `/` closing code to the inputs like I did in the demo.

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jtyUe/3/)**

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Agreed. It doesn't highlight **all** errors, just the first one, which I wouldn't do

Comment: @Ian, good point also, thanks. Fixed & now it highlights all errors.

Comment: @Sergio Yep, now that you don't `return`, it allows all elements to be validated :)

Comment: @Sergio (just to help your already good code) You might want to explain a little what this is doing (even if it's semi-obvious). It only helps the OP and future (beginner) visitors

Comment: @Ian, yes, will do that, also the return false idea. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not trying to change your code, but here's how I'd organize it: http://jsfiddle.net/SznRc/ - it uses jQuery's native way of iterating over a jQuery object, and kind of simplifies the loop's code. I don't think `== 0` was a good choice for checking against, because it will be true if the input is `0`

Comment: @Ian think that is better than OP's also. Using .each is simplifying (thats why jQuery is good to have). I vote up your comment, if you post it as an answer I vote it up also ;)

Comment: This is exactly it. The problem I was having was stopping the loop, this does it. Thanks so much! (I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation yet).

Answer (score 1):

Keep a boolean value outside the loop that is `true` only when all fields are not empty:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var all_good = true;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < personalInfo.length; ii++) {
        if ($(personalInfo[ii]).val() !== "") { // not empty
            $(personalInfoLabels[ii]).addClass("required");
            all_good = false;
        } else {
            $(personalInfoLabels[ii]).removeClass("required"); 
        }
    };
    if (all_good) {
        $("button").parent("fieldset").slideUp();
    }
});
```

By the way:

```
$(personalInfo[ii]).val() == 0
```

works because of coericion, which is a little hard to see. I'd just write:

```
$(personalInfo[ii]).val() === "" // or
$(personalInfo[ii]).val().length === 0
```

Because that is what you *mean*.

values from input fields are *always* strings, never numbers so you can even use `===` because you know the type is `string`. Similarly, `String.length` is *always* a `number`.

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Add a opening curly before `// not empty` to fix.

Comment: Not that it's up to you, but you might want to `$.trim()` the input value before comparing to `""`. I know the OP didn't know about it, but it's usually a good suggestion when validating a required field because spaces shouldn't count

Comment: And you also might want to keep the `else { $(personalInfoLabels[ii]).removeClass("required"); }`, otherwise future submits wouldn't clear newly valid fields, right? **EDIT:** Realized the `else` I saw was from Sergio's answer, not the OP's code. Still a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Validate first and `.slideUp()` at the end if all is well. **[Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bjKX7/4/)**

```
// validate first
for (var ii = 0; ii < personalInfo.length; ii++) {
    if ($(personalInfo[ii]).val() == 0) $(personalInfoLabels[ii]).addClass("required");
}

// check if there are any marked as required, if not, slideUp
var fs = $("#cont-one").parent("fieldset");
if (fs.find('.required').length == 0) fs.slideUp();
```